# How to set different index name for each row when using pd.concat and export output by .to_csv

Tags: python, csv, concatenation

I have this code that can merge multiple csv files by row ( horizontally) with header already available in each file:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import glob

interesting_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
df_list = []
similarity = ['(add)']
for csv_file in sorted(interesting_files):
    if any(pattern in csv_file for pattern in similarity):
        df_list.append(pd.read_csv(csv_file))#, header=None))
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True, axis=0,)
df.to_csv("_Combined_.csv", index=False)
```

But the index column of the output shows number in order, I want to set the index column to a column of different category for each row. How to do it?

current csv output:

```
    a b c d
0   1 2 3 4
1   5 6 7 8
2   9 1 2 3
```

I have tried with creating a list of index and merge them together but as I doubted, result looks like this:

```
      a b c d
mel   
bou   
rne   
  0   1 2 3 4
  1   5 6 7 8
  2   9 1 2 3
```

While here is my expected output:

```
      a b c d
mel   1 2 3 4
bou   5 6 7 8
rne   9 1 2 3
```

Comment: Add this index column as a usual column and then set as index: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Comment: This seems to be not working in my case though.